# Format simple array in multidimensional

Tags: php, array, converting

I have a simple array in PHP like this :

```
Array
(
    [max_size_video] => 50000
    [max_size_photo] => 8000
    [token_expire] => 100
    [dns] => mydns.fr
    ...
)
```

I would like to convert this array to multidimensional format with underscore as a separator:

```
Array
(
    [max] => Array
        (
            [size] => Array
                (
                    [video] => 50000
                    [photo] => 8000
                )
        )
    [token] => Array
        (
            [expire] => 100
        )
    [dns] => mydns.fr
    ...
)
```

I can do this with the following ugly code :

```
$item = explode('_', $row);
switch (count($item)) {
  case 1:
    $array[$item[0]] = $value;
  break;
  case 2:
    $array[$item[0]][$item[1]] = $value;
  break;
  case 3:
    $array[$item[0]][$item[1]][$item[2]] = $value;
  break;
  case 3:
    $array[$item[0]][$item[1]][$item[2]][$item[3]] = $value;
  break;
  ...
}
```

How can I do this with a more elegant function?

Answer (score 2):

A reference variable will save you from that wicked code bloat!

You can make iterative calls of [this Stack Overflow answer from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9636021/2943403).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/pcGhM))

```
function assignArrayByPath(&$arr, $path, $value, $separator = '_') {
    $keys = explode($separator, $path);
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $arr = &$arr[$key];
    }
    $arr = $value;
}
    
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    unset($array[$key]);
    assignArrayByPath($array, $key, $value);
}
var_export($array);
```

---

Or boil it down to this: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/EnIPt))

```
function assignArrayByPath(&$result, $path, $value) {
    foreach (explode('_', $path) as $key) {
        $result = &$result[$key];
    }
    $result = $value;
}

$result = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    assignArrayByPath($result, $key, $value);
}
var_export($result);
```

This technique will require that you build logical (non-monkey-wrenching) paths as keys.  I mean:

1. If after `'max_size_photo' => 8000`, you declare `'max' => 10000`, then you will get an error.
2. If after `'max_size_photo' => 8000`, you declare `'max_size' => 10000`, then you will erase the previously expanded (deeper) elements from the output array.

---

p.s. You can also write it without any custom functions by nesting the loops so long as you maintain the technique of using a reference variable inside of a reference variable.  Trippy, right?

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Vd6r8))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $path => $value) {
    $ref = &$result;
    foreach (explode('_', $path) as $key) {
        $ref = &$ref[$key];
    }
    $ref = $value;
}
var_export($result);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It’s for get data in a database, and send in json at my frontend

Comment: If you have any power to change the database values, it would be better to convert this data to JSON **before** saving it to the database.  Then you only need to call the standard `json_decode()` when you pull the row.  Modern versions of MySQL offer JSON manipulations too (but you might not need them for your usage).

Comment: @mickmackusa what's the logic behind having `assignArrayByPath` as a function as opposed to a simple nested loop?

Comment: @Steven I added the nested loop version.

Answer (score 0):

Mick already provided a good solution per hour question.

Bearing in mind it might have just been for illustration purposes, I noticed the `switch` statement has a redundant case:

```
 case 3:
    $array[$item[0]][$item[1]][$item[2]] = $value;
  break;
  case 3:
    $array[$item[0]][$item[1]][$item[2]][$item[3]] = $value;
  break;
```

Here the second `case 3` is unreachable- perhaps it was a typo and should have been  `case 4`. This won’t lead to an error but is excess lines of code that could lead to confusion for anyone reading the code- including your future self!